# Matplotlib can't give up old argument

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I made a mistake in a command to matplotlib:

```
newline.=plot((x0,x1),(y0,y1),color='light grey')
```

Turns out there is no "light grey".  Well, I figured I could fix it:

```
newline.remove()
newerline,=plot((x0,x1),(y0,y1),color='grey')
```

But Matplotlib returns the same horrendously long error message, with the root problem being

```
exc = ValueError(u'to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "light grey"\ncould not convert string to float: light grey',)
```

That is, somehow, Matplotlib thinks I am still trying to plot with "light grey".  I have tried a few things to get around this, but it just won't give up the light grey problem.  It's like I offended it or something.  Anyone have any ideas?  This is a pretty complex plot.  I really don't want to tear it down and start again.

If it matters, I am running python on Enthought Canopy 1.5.2, Linux.

Comment: Are you running in the Canopy ipython window? Does `%hist` get you your commands? If the plot's too complex to tear down surely converting it to a script would be worth it.

Comment: @cphlewis Thanks.  %hist should do the job for now.  If anyone knows what causes this error in the first place, though, I would love to find out!

Comment: No-one else has your code to debug -- I think you should capture it from before the erroneous "light grey", keep it as a script, and start tidying it up both to find the sticky problem and to have a reusable copy of your complex plot. (Probably matplotlib isn't offended. If it has developed sentience, we want to know. :))